# C++ tmpnam alternative

Tags: c++, temporary-files

I have a C++ library that uses `tmpnam(NULL)` to create a temporary file.

I need to hack this because it makes the temp file in  the root folder ("c:" or "/") and so it needs the administrative privileges.
How can I change this function with other one using a valid temp path?

Thanks.

Comment: What operating system?

Comment: *I need to hack this because it makes the temp file in the root folder ("c:" or "/")* According to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355.aspx) *tmpnam returns a name unique in the current working directory* -- switch your cwd out of C: ?

Answer (score 4):

Though `tmpnam` returns a filename pre-pended by `/` - it actually denotes a unique filename in the current directory and not `/` or `c:\`. So you can `chdir` to any other directory before calling `tmpnam` to find a unique filename for that directory.

You can also call `tempnam` instead of `tmpnam` which allows takes a directory name as input.

Comment: Be warned that current Linux man page says "Never use this function.  Use mkstemp(3) or tmpfile(3) instead".