# fopen of file name created by tmpnam fails on mingw

Tags: c++, c, windows, mingw, mingw-w64

I have a program that generates a temporary filename via `tmpname` and attempts to open that file afterwards via `fopen`. However, this consistently fails when the program is built using MinGW, but consistently works on the same machine when built using VS2015. Here is a simple test:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    char fname[L_tmpnam];
    if(!tmpnam(fname)) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    printf("%s\n", fname);
    FILE * f = fopen(fname, "wb");
    if(!f) return EXIT_FAILURE;
    fclose(f);
    remove(fname);
    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Building and running using gcc via

```
gcc test.c && a && echo ok || echo failed
```

outputs

```
\s4so.
failed
```

Built and run using VS2015 via

```
cl test.c && test && echo ok || echo failed
```

produces

```
%TMP%\s11w.0
ok
```

where `%TMP%` is the value of the TMP environment variable.

The reason for the failure is obvious (MinGW does not add the TMP folder and instead tries to write to the root directory of the current drive to which the user does not have write access). However, why does this happen? Am I missing a call, or is this a bug?

Comment: Maybe [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/18570757/3436922) helps

Comment: You can what happens using `perror`: `if(!tmpnam(fname)) {perror("tmpnam"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE);}`

Comment: @AlterMann I think `tmpnam` successes 'cause the return value is checked. The problem is that the returned file name point to root  and the program is not allowed to write there..

Comment: @LPs not really. A filename beginning with a slash in windows is relative to the current partition root, not to the current folder. something neither the top voted comment nor the top voted answer appear to understand on that question. Also behavior obviously differs between MSVC and MinGW so I can't simply prepend a dot or something.

Comment: @AlterMann failure of tmpnam is already reported via the return code. And it doesn't fail.

Comment: @LPs, oh, I see, then I suggest to check `perror("fopen");`

Comment: @AlterMann the return code of fopen is checked as well. that is not the issue.

Comment: I have similar behavior in cygwin64, `tmpnam` will answer \s4so. not even trying to prepend a %TMP% directory (but such substitution does not make sense in cygwin, does it?). It badly breaks programs using `tmpnam` (for example, I cannot compile ATLAS http://math-atlas.sourceforge.net/).

Answer (score 1):

> However, why does this happen? Am I missing a call, or is this a bug?

The standard doesn't specify where the file is to be located. So this is not a bug, it's an example of two different implementations of `tmpnam`

BTW: Before Visual C++ 2015, Visual C++ also used the root of the drive. See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531344.aspx

Comment: That the standard doesn't specify where it should be located does not mean that an implementation that never returns a usable path should be considered "ok". But good to know that MSVC used to have the same bug. Probably just an artifact of MinGW blindly using msvcrt.dll (which technically shouldn't be used at all)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hs3e7355.aspx)

> - If the TMP environment variable is defined and set to a valid directory name, unique file names will be generated for the directory specified by TMP.
> - If the TMP environment variable is not defined or if it is set to the name of a directory that does not exist, `_tempnam` will use the dir parameter as the path for which it will generate unique names.
> - If the TMP environment variable is not defined or if it is set to the name of a directory that does not exist, and if dir is either NULL or set to the name of a directory that does not exist, `_tempnam` will use the current working directory to generate unique names. Currently, if both TMP and dir specify names of directories that do not exist, the _tempnam function call will fail.

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

It seems that the behavior is redefined on windows.

That is not the linux behavior defined my [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpnam.3.html)

> The pathname that is created, has a directory prefix `P_tmpdir`.  (Both
>          L_tmpnam and **P_tmpdir are defined in `<stdio.h>`**, just like the `TMP_MAX`
>          mentioned below.)

<sup>Emphasis mine</sup>

On my system `P_tmpdir` is set to `"/tmp"` and the code works well returning `/tmp/something`

Moreover looking into stdio.h you can find out that the declaration of P_tmpdir has conditions:

```
#if defined __USE_SVID || defined __USE_XOPEN
/* Default path prefix for `tempnam' and `tmpnam'.  */
# define P_tmpdir   "/tmp"
#endif
```

Take care of those settings: on my `features.h` file `__USE_SVID` is define to `1`

In simple words: **you have to take care of the platform because windows behave differently than linux**

Comment: changing the definition of `_P_tmpdir` does not magically change what `tmpnam` returns. For MinGW the only flag affecting `_P_tmpdir` `POSIX` which chooses between `"/"` and `"\\"`. Furthermore `/tmp` would be just as wrong on Windows.

Comment: @Joe Sorry, I'm not getting you.

Comment: the change would have to be done at compile time of the CRT.

Comment: the whole `P_tmpdir` is also a POSIX thing, and not related to the C standard at all, which only specifies that `tmpnam` "[...] generates a string that is a valid file name and that is not the same
as the name of an existing file."

Comment: Did you look at the linked linux [man](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/tmpnam.3.html)? It isn't a "POSIX thing" , is is conforming to C89, C99. Moreover `gcc` with `-std=c11` wanrs: `warning: the use of `tmpnam' is dangerous, better use `mkstemp'`

Comment: That it conforms to C89/C99 doesn't mean that `P_tmpdir` wasn't added by POSIX (which it was), and is not part of the C standard. `mkstemp` is a POSIX function that does not exist on Windows, which is why that warning doesn't exist on windows.

Comment: BTW The issue is: that function has different implementations between platforms. So you have to manage those differences, as stated in the answer.